# WCF OperationContract method marked for IsTerminating throwing exception when called by client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, unity-game-engine, mono

I am writing some Demos for testing the viability of using `WCF` with a game written in Unity3d.
I am drawn towards the sheer convenience of `WCF` Service and Operation contracts.
I have 2 programs I am dealing with in this demo.
The first is my `Unity3D` application, which basically is a cube. I have the `Unity3d` program hosting a Service which allows a client to connect to it and increase or decrease the cube's velocity of rotation around x,y and z axes.

The Service looks like this.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://WCF.WithUnity.Samples", SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface ICubeSpin
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
    void Init();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void AddYaw();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void SubYaw();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void AddPitch();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void SubPitch();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void AddRoll();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void SubRoll();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void ResetZero();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
    void Close();
}
```

My client application is simply a `.net 3.5` console application which looks like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace UnityCubeSpinControllerClient
{
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using WCFClient;

    class UnityCubeSpinControllerClient
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChannelFactory<ICubeSpin> tcpFactory = new ChannelFactory<ICubeSpin>(new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8002/CubeSpin"));

            ICubeSpin cubeSpinProxy = tcpFactory.CreateChannel();

            cubeSpinProxy.Init();

            bool running = true;
            while (running)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();

                switch (keyInfo.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                        running = false;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        cubeSpinProxy.AddPitch();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        cubeSpinProxy.SubPitch();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                        cubeSpinProxy.SubRoll();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                        cubeSpinProxy.AddRoll();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.PageUp:
                        cubeSpinProxy.AddYaw();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.PageDown:
                        cubeSpinProxy.SubYaw();
                        break;
                }
            }

            cubeSpinProxy.Close();
            tcpFactory.Close();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `TCP` binding because apparently named pipes aren't easy to get working in unity3d, or possibly not implemented at all in `Unity3d`'s supplied Mono version (and yes, I use the .net 2.0 instead of the .net 2.0 subset setting).

Everything runs perfectly, to a point.

Now, to the problem.
The problem is that when my client calls the Close() method, if the user presses the escape key, the client itself always throws an exception of:

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException -  Additional information: Error
>   while reading message framing format at position 1 of stream (state:
>   Start)

The inner exception shows :

> System.IO.InvalidDataException -  {"More data was expected, but EOF
>   was reached."}

No exceptions are reported by the host.

I am not entirely sure why this is happening. 
Since my `unity3d` program is the host for the service, it'll probably be quite difficult to get `WCF` tracing working on it. I could probably look into getting it working on the client, but it seems to me that since the `ICubeSpin.Close()` method is so simple, and marked with what I believe are the correct attributes, there really won't be much to trace.

Anyone have an idea of what is going on here?

Comment: did you tried with "using ( ICubeSpin cubeSpinProxy = tcpFactory.CreateChannel()) { ... }" ?

Comment: Maybe you should avoid using init()/close() actions with a client.  Your service should be stateless (with implicit init/close inside your server)

Comment: @hugo, why should my service be stateless? I want to ensure that the work to establish the connection need not be done multiple times. Why should I have the overhead of creating an WCF object each time I need to send a message? I have session mode = required on purpose. My metrics show much improved performance if I do not have to keep re-establishing the connection from client to server each time I want to do something.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  Can you try with another binding using http?  Execute this test to check if it's not a binding configuration problem.  Maybe you need to specify some more options with tcp binding (I'm not used of that binding)